# How to integrate .sh file into .pkg app file

Tags: xcode, macos

Am trying to integrate a .sh(script file) into my .pkg app file, I have tried the following command in terminal -

```
pkgbuild --root /Users/MyName/Documents/Applications/MyApp.app --identifier com.Companyname.MyApp --scripts /Users/MyName/Desktop/Files/postinstall.sh --install-location /Users/MyName/Documents/Applications/MyApp.app  /Users/MyName/Documents/Applications/a.pkg
```

I have a script file that makes a directory -

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#postinstall

cd /Users/mohammedtalhahussain/Desktop/Files 
mkdir floder

exit 0
```

**The problem** - the script file(.sh) is not being executed(its is not creating directory)
**NOTE**: I have saved the script file(.sh) locally

Any help is appreciated,
Regards.

Comment: I think the parameter to the `--scripts` option is supposed to be a *directory* containing scripts, not an individual script. Also, in scripts you should always check whether `cd` succeeds (and probably exit if it doesn't) so that the rest of the script won't just keep running in some completely imappropriate place in the filesystem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried that too but it didn't work ,where should I place this script file , should I place it in the project ? or can I place it locally(eg: in my desktop folder)?

Comment: My problem was solved after referring this - https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd08744

Comment: You should summarize the solution, post it as an answer and then (after 48 hours) accept it. See the help topic ["Can I answer my own question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)